# Lync : CanInvoke returning false while downloading attachment

Tags: lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I have code which sends a file to a client & on another side I'm receiving it using ContentAdded event. That event gets raised but CanInvoke is returning false. Where I'm getting wrong?

```
void _sharingModality_ContentAdded(object sender, ContentCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Type == ShareableContentType.NativeFile)
        {
            int hr;
            if (e.Item.CanInvoke(ShareableContentAction.DownloadFile, out hr))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("download event raised");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("u cannot invoke download");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

(Note: I'm using Lync client 2013)

**EDIT 1:**

CanInvoke returns true if I put a message box before that statement, otherwise returns false. Is it affecting some background thread or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer. The state of `ShareableContent` that is our file is `Connecting` while I'm firing CanInvoke on it. The file can only be downloaded when state changes to `Online`. So by handling `ShareableContent.StateChanged` event I made it work. So simple but took so much time because of very poor documentation.

[MSDN reference here..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.sharing.shareablecontentstate_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncctrsl.aspx)